# Endless loop in IIS worker process while at system speech synthesizer

Tags: text-to-speech, speech

Im using System.Speech for Text-to-Speech, it executes and create the audio file well by SetOutputToWaveFile while at debugging, if I configured the application through IIS, it recycle the loop in IIS worker process.

While at Diagnol test of IIS, it shows the argument exception "Failed to create an instance for the CLSID associated with this token"
And Im working on the .net c# application, VS2010 ultimate, OS windows server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5

Thanks for advance in helps to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using System.Speech for TTS.  You should be using Microsoft.Speech.  The desktop TTS engines aren't set up to run in a service like IIS typically does, and the server TTS engines are.

Comment: How to use desktop TTS engines in Microsoft.Speech

Comment: @charulathakrishnamoorthy You don't.